# Can not boot ubuntu

Tags: boot

I made a boot-repair from terminal, and set the pre installed windows 8 to sda2, and afterwards when I start ubuntu the screen looked funny, and then I used recovery from the start, and now every time I boot ubuntu it's comes whit shell where I can type in user name and password, and my problem is what to type in at the shell root so I can use ubuntu again, I also tried an USB stick whit ubuntu but still can come to ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are going into shell by default now. You need to reboot, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> for a second, then select advanced recovery mode. After that, go to root user and enter the command below:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
sudo passwd root
```

Then enter the new password for root and type the command below:

```
startx
```

Desktop window will work again.

Comment: Thanks. But can not still boot when says Xinit: unable to connect to X server: connection refused. Xinit: server error